# XLConnect installation fails in R for windows

Tags: r, xlconnect

I installed R studio Version 1.2.1335 and R version 3.5.2

I'm trying to install the `XLconnect` package but I keep getting this 
error: `there is no package called 'XLConnect'`

```
install.packages("XLConnect")

WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/ also installing the dependency ‘XLConnectJars’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/XLConnectJars_0.2-15.zip' Content type 'application/zip' length 14789155 bytes (14.1 MB) downloaded 14.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/XLConnect_0.2-15.zip' Content type 'application/zip' length 9832001 bytes (9.4 MB) downloaded 9.4 MB

package ‘XLConnectJars’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked Warning in install.packages :   cannot remove prior installation of package ‘XLConnectJars’ package ‘XLConnect’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked Warning in install.packages :   cannot remove prior installation of package ‘XLConnect’

The downloaded binary packages are in   C:\Users\hamaor\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWAe4XU\downloaded_packages
library("XLConnect") 
Error in library("XLConnect") : there is no package called ‘XLConnect’
.libPaths()

[1] "F:/Dropbox/tools/R-3.5.2/library"
```

When I look in that directory, I see that `XLConnect` is there.  (I also tried to install Java 64bit as recommended in other posts.)

I appreciate any help

Comment: **Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed** Did you install Rtools?

Comment: thanks it solved my problem!